how to connect Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish) to wifi? currently not connected
I'm trying to connect my Ubuntu server to WiFi, but it doesn't have an existing internet connection. I've already attempted configuration using netplan and wpa_supplicant, but unfortunately, the server still isn't connecting.
I have used networkd as renderer and when i do sudo netplan apply, i get: Unit openvswitch-switch.service could not found
Any advice on how to achieve this without an initial wired connection?
